# Getting annoying exclamation sound (a.k.a "Ding") on calling button_click from key press even after suppressing keypress

Tags: c#

So the password field is coded to call the "LogIn" button on Enter. If the credentials entered are wrong, the control goes to the catch block and the messagebox is shown.

When the user enters wrong username/password and hits enter, the button_click method is called, control goes to the catch block and the messagebox is shown along with a super annoying "ding" (why do they even have that?).

However, that sound doesn't come when the user clicks the button after wrong username/password even the the method is same.

Needless to say I've set SuppressedKeyPress. Please help. Thanks

Textbox_KeyDown():

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button2_Click(sender, new EventArgs());

            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Button_click() :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            ......
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User does not exist");  //Where the ding occurs only on keypress and not on direct button click
        }

    }
```

I suspect it is because of the object and eventargs arguements passed during button_click call but then again, I'm just a noob. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by not using events to call the `button2_Click` event handler, but by setting the `AcceptButton` of the form to `button2`. That means that when you hit enter on any input control, it will call the button's click event.